# JavaScript generate json data from array or function for nivo

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to plot sine wave using Nivo but the data has to be in a specific format that I'm unable to achieve. the output should look like {{x:1,y:1},{x:2,y:4},{x:3,y:8},....}

Nivo format:

```
dataobject[]required
Chart data.
Chart data, which must conform to this structure:

Array<{
    id:   string | number
    data: Array<{
        x: number | string | Date
        y: number | string | Date
    }>
}>
```

My code:

```
class Data{
  constructor(x){
    this.x=x
    this.y=Math.sin(x)
  }
    values() {
      return { x:this.x,y:this.y}
   } 
}

function create(){
  let i
  let data= {}
  let temp
  for(i=0;i<100;i++){
    temp=new Data(i)
    data['']=temp.values()
  }
  console.log(data)
}
```

output:

```
    {"": {…}}
"":
x: 99
y: -0.9992068341863537
__proto__: Object
__proto__:
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ toString()
valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

**UPDATE:**
creating an empty array  pushing into it worked thanks for the answers

```
function create(){
  let i
  let data= []
  let temp
  for(i=0;i<(22/7*2*10*10);i++){
    temp=new Data(i/10)
    data.push(temp.values())
  }
  console.log(data)
  return data
}
```

[Nivo line plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4e2lc.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think data should be an array.

Try this:

```
class Data{
  constructor(x){
    this.x=x
    this.y=Math.sin(x)
  }
    values() {
      return { x:this.x,y:this.y}
   } 
}

function create(){
  let i
  let data= []
  let temp
  for(i=0;i<100;i++){
    temp=new Data(i)
    data.push({id:i, data:temp.values()})
  }
  console.log(data)
}
create()
```

Explanation:
The folowing means that data shoulld be an array of objects with two values.

1. id: should be a string or a number
2. data: should be an object with a value of x and y

> ```
> Array<{
>     id:   string | number
>     data: Array<{
>         x: number | string | Date
>         y: number | string | Date
>     }>
> }>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of Nivo before, but I can help you understand why your data isn't formatted the way you want it.

It appears you want something like:

`[ {x:0,y:Math.sin(0)}, {x:1,y:Math.sin(1)}, ... ]`

Now let's look at your "create" function:

You create an empty object named 'data'. Next thing you do, you iterate over i from 0 to 99, doing the following:

`temp=new Data(i)`

Which sets your temp variable to a new Data class member (with i in its constructor).

`data['']=temp.values()`

Which sets the "" (i.e. empty string) property of your data object variable to the return of the Data(i).values. So each loop inside your for is always going to overwrite the previous one.
What you need to do is initialize data as an empty array (data = []), and then data.push() the points you want, as pointed out by the other answer here. Just hoped to share some insight as to why this isn't working, as opposed to just give you an answer

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is invalid **you cant do  {{x:1,y:1},{x:2,y:4},{x:3,y:8},....}** because each object in an JSON-object needs a name like
{"a":{x:1,y:1}, "b":{x:2,y:4}....}.
But you could just store the data in an array like this [{x:1,y:1},{x:2,y:4},{x:3,y:8},....]

```
 function create(){
  let i
  let data= [] //Array
  let temp
  for(i=0;i<100;i++){
    temp=new Data(i)
    data.push(temp.values()) //add the new value
  }
  console.log(data)
}
```

I don't know if Math.sin(x) is what you want for this.y because it's not giving the results you defined but I can't help you with that. Run the snippet to see what the result of the new create function is.

```js
function Data(x) {
 this.x=x
    this.y=Math.sin(x)
    
    this.values = function() {
      return { x:this.x,y:this.y}
   } 
}

 function create(){
  let i
  let data= [] //Array
  let temp
  for(i=0;i<100;i++){
    temp=new Data(i)
    data.push(temp.values()) //add the new value
  }
  console.log(data);
}

create();
```

I also want to mention that you did data['']=temp.values() and that's the reason you only had one value in your object because you assigned your new value 100 times to the same name in the JSON object (data).